# Uno Platform Using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, cross-platform, inversion-of-control, uno-platform

I am trying to inject dependencies into a constructor of a ViewModel in a project using the Mvvm framework. I am using the Uno Platform. I tried Mvvm frameworks Prism and Mvvmcross but they remain incomplete and I couldn't get them to build. I am now trying Mvvmhelpers which builds fine but I don't think that caters for a IOC container.Could someone recommned a way forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uno Platform can use any .NET Standard library, so you could potentially just install Autofac or Unity and plug it into your custom MVVM framework.

**MvvmLight** binding is provided via [Uno.MvvmLight](https://github.com/nventive/uno.mvvmlight), which is also available as a [NuGet package in preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uno.GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform/5.4.0-uno.134). Although it hasn't been updated for a while, I will put up a Issue on GitHub to get it up to date again with the upstream.

For my personal favorite **MvvmCross** - there is a [work in progress PR on GitHub](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/3495), which will bring Uno support directly into MvvmCross. But before that happens, you can follow the instructions from **Nick Randolph** [on his blog](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/uno-with-mvvmcross/) to get the preview version up and running.

The platform is still quite new so it takes time for things to settle and third party libraries to adopt it, but after the release of WinUI 3.0 it should stabilize and the support should grow faster.

### Update

I totally forgot to mention [**ReactiveUI**](https://reactiveui.net/) which has first-party support for Uno Platform already.

Comment: Yes of course you are right about new platforms. I followed the instructions on Nick's blog closely but I just couldntt get it to work - I think the problem was in the StarterApp class which would n't build. It so frustrating not to be able to use MVVM on such a promising platform.

Comment: Don't worry, it is coming and very soon :-) . The team has only limited resources at hand while they are doing so many different things at once, that's why there are still things like this missing. But if you have some spare time, any help and contributions are very appreciated :-)

Comment: I would but believe I would be out my depth.

Comment: Definitely not :-) ! You can start with any contribution, no matter how small. Documentation, bug fixes, anything is warmly welcome :-)

Comment: Updated my answer with ReactiveUI, which already has first-party support

Comment: How would I get the MS ServiceCollection to work with Uno so that anything I register in the ServiceCollection is injected into pages?

Comment: @PeterMorris UWP/Uno Pages must have a parameterless constructor so that Frame can perform navigation. That being said, dependency injection could be implemented for page's view models. I haven't tried that with ServiceCollection yet, but it is a good idea and I will try to make some simple MVVM infrastructure with Microsoft's dependency injection and write a blog about it :-)

Comment: @PeterMorris actually noticed this blog post shows Uno with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection - https://platform.uno/blog/getting-started-with-uno-platform-and-reactiveui/

Comment: Prism.Uno is supposed to be eligible to inject deps into Win UI ctors but only if the Win UI  project is being created in the Uno's ecosystem. Could you drop a guide how Win UI and Prism can incorporate via Uno ?